# using reportlab table creator I get an error saying Table takes no parameters

Tags: python, python-2.7, reportlab

I am using the example on [this site](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/09/21/reportlab-tables-creating-tables-in-pdfs-with-python/) to create a table in a PDF file, using `reportlab` and I get a error saying

```
TypeError: object.__new__() takes no parameters
```

on the line that has this line of code,

```
t=Table(data)
```

I am running this code:

```
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle

doc = SimpleDocTemplate("simple_table.pdf", pagesize=letter)
# container for the 'Flowable' objects
elements = []

data= [['00', '01', '02', '03', '04'],
       ['10', '11', '12', '13', '14'],
       ['20', '21', '22', '23', '24'],
       ['30', '31', '32', '33', '34']]
t=Table(data)
t.setStyle(TableStyle([('BACKGROUND',(1,1),(-2,-2),colors.green),
                       ('TEXTCOLOR',(0,0),(1,-1),colors.red)]))
elements.append(t)
# write the document to disk
doc.build(elements)
```

Thanks,

Comment: are you sure your not importing a different Table class somewhere?  your example file runs fine for me ... what version of reportlab are you using?

Comment: Its version 2.5 and when I run it by it in its own .py file with no other code it works fine.  Really what I want to do is add a table to a existing PDF that I have created.

Comment: I got it to work by just using canvas.grid, thanks for the help Joran.

Comment: lol glad to hear... not sure how much help i was :P